# Why is H2O a weaker acid than acetylacetone? Shouldn't a hydrogen connected to an oxygen be more acidic than a hydrogen connected to a carbon atom?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, reaction-mechanism

I recently started studying chemistry after a long pause in my education so pardon me if it is a simple question.

In the organic chemistry course I am taking, the professor told us that the first factor defining the stability of the conjugate base (and thereby the acidity of the compound) is the atom that is connected to the acidic hydrogen. By this definition, the hydrogen in $\ce{H2O}$ should be more acidic than the hydrogen in acetylacetone as the first one is connected to oxygen but the second one is connected to carbon (as oxygen is more electronegative than carbon).

My professor mentioned other factors such as the existence of resonance structures, inductive polarity, and the effect of side chains, but she mentioned these factors come next and only if both hydrogens in our comparison are bound to the same element.

Comment: Compare comparable. Water is stronger acid than e.g. methane. And If you replace the central -CH2- by -OH, then resulting acetic acid is stronger acid than acetylacetone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your instructor is right, up to a certain point. There are factors that are more important (the atom to which it is bound) and factors that are less important (resonance, etc.), and it's good to be able to order these relative factors. The devil is in the details, though. If your resonance stabilisation is strong enough (and in this case it is) then it can overcome the more important factor.

Before starting, let me point out that CH's *are* less acidic than OH's, but **this isn't actually to do with electronegativity**. If it was about electronegativity, then OH's should be more acidic than SH's as O is more electronegative than S, but the opposite is true. Same applies to HF and HCl: F is more electronegative but HF is actually a weak acid. It has more to do with the X–H single bond strength than anything, as a weaker bond is easier to break (homolytically). The X–H heterolytic cleavage, relevant for an acid–base reaction, is sort of like a homolytic cleavage, plus an electron transfer from H to X. The electronegativity comes into play in the electron transfer step, but it's just not so important a consideration, compared to the bond strength which describes the homolytic cleavage.

---

I'm giving p*K*<sub>a</sub>'s to the nearest 5(ish) in this discussion. The exact numbers don't matter too much, we're more interested in broader trends.

If you compare water and methane, their p*K*<sub>a</sub>'s are ~15 and ~50 respectively, which is a difference of about 35 units. That's roughly how much the adjacent-atom factor counts for, when comparing C and O.

If you then compare acetone and methane, p*K*<sub>a</sub>'s are ~20 and ~50 respectively, which is a difference of about 30 units. Not quite as big as the previous one, which was 35.

Acetylacetone, though, has *two* carbonyl groups, that's twice as many as in acetone. Now, resonance stabilisation doesn't scale linearly in that fashion and hence the additional stabilisation over acetone is only ~10 units. However, it's still enough to bring the p*K*<sub>a</sub> down to ~10, which is more acidic than water.

Answer (score 2):

We really need to think carefully about a lot of things when thinking about acid/base reactions: charge, resonance/aromaticity, electronegativity, hybridization, and occasionally things like sterics (things like proton sponge) or reversibility (for instance where one product is emitted as a gas like in the case of NaH). In many cases these factors are interconnected.
[image]

The primary stabilization factor in the deprotonated form of acetylacetone is the delocalization of the negative charge via resonance onto the oxygen atoms (both delocalizing charge across several atoms and placing the negative charge on the more electronegative oxygen atoms). Secondarily, the resultant anion forms a conjugated system. The actual structure is a weighted linear combination of three structures, called a resonance hybrid, where two of the constituent resonance structures place the negative charge on a the electronegative oxygen atom are weighted more heavily.